# Problem with install Oxygen-Transparent theme on Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, themes, kde, oxygen

I would like to install `Oxygen-Transparent` theme on Kubuntu 12.04.
(`the KDE version is 4.11.2`)

To install that :

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential cmake kdelibs5-dev
```

and then :

```
sudo apt-get install kdebase-workspace-dev libxrender-dev libx11-dev git
```

Above command get me an error :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
git is already the newest version.
libx11-dev is already the newest version.
libx11-dev set to manually installed.
libxrender-dev is already the newest version.
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 kdebase-workspace-dev : Depends: kde-workspace-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Please tell me what am i missing here?

Any helps would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you try to do:

```
sudo apt-get install kde-workspace-dev
```

It will show something like this:

```
kde-workspace-dev : Depends: libkwinglesutils1 (= 4:4.8.5-0ubuntu0.3) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libkwinactiveglesutils1 (= 4:4.8.5-0ubuntu0.3) but it is not going to be installed
```

Then again:

```
sudo apt-get install libkwinglesutils1 libkwinactiveglesutils1
```

And Now you can try again your former command:

```
sudo apt-get install kdebase-workspace-dev libxrender-dev libx11-dev git
```